# Send a broadcast only to specific Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, intentservice

I have one *Activity* which creates a *BroadcastReceiver* with an *IntentFilter* in the method `onCreate(...)`:

```
IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter("action");

receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
};

registerReceiver(receiver, iFilter);
```

On the other side is an *IntentService*, which shall send some data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), receiver.class);
intent.setAction("action");

[...]

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But it seems not to work. No *Broadcast* ist received.
My service class is in an android lib, perhaps this makes trouble.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: It should work. why do you think it doesn't work. It doesn't matter if it's in a library project, as long as you reference your library project in your main project.

Comment: I don't think it. I noticed it while testing.

Comment: Log or print something in the onRecieve method. What does logcat say?

Comment: Nothing is printed or logged which belongs to the Activity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just create the intent with your action.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("action");
[...]
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And consider renaming "action" to something more meaningful, like "com.my.package.actions.SOME_ACTION".

If you only want that your application components receive the broadcast then use:

1. Register a permission in your Manifest with a `signature` protection level (and define a use-permission for that permission). More [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html).
2. Use [`sendBroadcast(intent, permission)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29), and specify the permission in 1.

Comment: There are named more meaningful. ;) When I use that way everyone can receive my *Broadcast* and that I want to prevent.

Comment: That's the idea of a broadcast event. What do you mean by everyone? Your activities should stop listening somewhere in their lifecycle, probably in the onPause method.

Comment: I mean a *Broadcast* can received with different Activities not only my own, can't it?

Comment: Oh ok. Yes they can listen for your intents, but they would need to know the name of the action.

Answer (score 6):

if the intent is inside your app only, consider using [**LocalBroadcastManager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)